# REST: soapUI groovy script not running on tomcat server

Tags: rest, groovy, tomcat7, soapui

I have a problem about executing groovy script of my rest mock service project on tomcat server.

Actually i'm using soapUI pro 5.1.0 to create a complete REST web services with the mock service.
Indeed, after resources creation (/api/1/mobile/users), I create a method POST that contains several requests and I generate the corresponding REST responses under (/api/1/mobile/users) resource. Then to have the corresponding response for each request I develop a groovy script that check the request content and send the right response. The script is well performed locally in the soapUI tool, but when I deploy the project on tomcat server, and try to send request with the client. I noticed that the default response is sent for all requests instead of targeted response. It seems that the script is not performed, and no log info is received.

Comment: I'm facing this issue with SOAP 5.2.1 , can you please share if you were able to resolve the above issue when deploying to tomcat.